# Uninstalling bloatware application using adb

Tags: android, adb, uninstallation

Hello all,

I want to remove applications that were on my phone since the beginning but I don't use them. I have Sony Xperia P and one of the apps I want to get rid of is **joyn**, which uses about 20% of battery although I don't use it and I also tried disabling all of its parts in *settings/applications* (with no luck).

I rooted my phone and tried to use adb to uninstall the app but the attempt always fails. 
What I did:

```
C:\adb -s YT9100UAAX shell
shell@android:/ $ su
```

The first time on the phone, I needed to allow access to super user in SuperSU application and from now on the ABD shell is in the list of elevated applications in SuperSU.

```
root@android:/ # pm uninstall com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller
Success
```

Regular application uninstallation works fine, but when I try to uninstall something else I get:

```
root@android:/ # pm uninstall com.orangelabs.rcs
Failure

root@android:/ # pm uninstall com.vodafone.vodafone360updates
Failure
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks for the help

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on  corsair992's advice I downloaded Titanium Backup and I was able to uninstall everything I wanted (incl. the bloatware). Didn't know this app was so powerful!

Thx a lot corsair992